# How to get unique value in each cell?

Tags: python, nlp

I am trying to extract skills from job description. But I cannot get unique word (each word is repeated). For example, word 'SQL' is repeated 2 time in row 5. I cannot use unique() for Dataframe as well. Is there any way to prevent from repeating the words?

```
list1={'SQL','visualization','modeling','sql','mysql','python','oracle','sybase','mathematics','collection','statistics','tableau','etl','nosql','weka','r','communication','microsoft','excel','pattern', 'recognition','machine','processing','mining','strategy','big','predictive'}

df['skill'] =df['description'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join([item for item in x.split( ) if item in list1]))

df.head(10)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PtN0N.png)

Comment: Would list one use square brackets instead of braces?

Comment: `list1 = [...]`, `withoutduplicates = list(set(list1))`. This just removes all duplicates when it converts to a set.

Comment: I've tried it, didn't work!

Comment: The original code, with the curly brackets, would be correct in this case, because that builds a set without duplicates.  In this case, you need to apply `list(set(...))` to the output of the `apply`.  That's where the duplicates are coming in.

Comment: @TimRoberts thank you for your help. I just tried, but still get duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

I imagine the following should work:

```
list1={'SQL','visualization','modeling','sql','mysql','python','oracle','sybase','mathematics','collection','statistics','tableau','etl','nosql','weka','r','communication','microsoft','excel','pattern', 'recognition','machine','processing','mining','strategy','big','predictive'}

df_nonsenior['skill'] =df_nonsenior['description'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join(list(set([item for item in x.split( ) if item in list1]))))

df_nonsenior.head(10)
```

As `[item for item in x.split( ) if item in list1]` is a list of all words, in order, in the description that also appear in list1. We need to filter out the duplicates from this list before joining the items into a string.

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked!!!!!

Comment: Do you know how I can put commas between the extracted words? So far it looks like:  python sql modeling.  I want to separate them so that I can do more analysis.Thanks!

Comment: The syntax of join is ```separator.join(iterable)```. At the moment your separator is ```' '```; if you want a different one, you can replace it, e.g. with ```', '```.